powershell activity if static string is on substring on file
i need to do an activity when are present a static string on file
if  ( Get-Content -Path C:\appoggio\*.TXT  -filter {$_.Substring(250,5)} ) = '05032' {
 Set-Location C:\appoggio\prova  -WhatIf
 Write-Warning 'ok'
}

the file
           2401188832220240801083447050320240100750910000101002076        IT0000007994            251630830000   00000002401001652820240801   00000000000000000000000000000000000000                              00  0000000000  9                      05032     0139200170.                             00000000

>  
 BATCH     2401188850220240801073602051230240100750980000101002076        IT0000006570            251765330000   00000002401001646020240801   000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000081fcc082              00  0000000000  9                      05123     0085800050.                             00000000


In the code you've shown you're attempting to call Substring(250, 5) - but the 05032 substring appears to be located at offset 32 and 245 (not 250) of "the file".

it's an error of paste, the position it's correct, but the comand not work

0532 in your sample would've to be .Substring(249, 5). How many .txt files are there? what you probably wanted to do was if ((Get-Content -Path C:\appoggio\*.TXT -Raw).Substring(249, 5) -eq '05032') { ... but that would probably fail if there are many txt files. Also there are more efficient ways of doing this if you explain further


Presumably, from your sample data, the startIndex argument on your SubString call should be 249:
$sample = @'
           2401188832220240801083447050320240100750910000101002076        IT0000007994            251630830000   00000002401001652820240801   00000000000000000000000000000000000000                              00  0000000000  9                      05032     0139200170.                             00000000

>
 BATCH     2401188850220240801073602051230240100750980000101002076        IT0000006570            251765330000   00000002401001646020240801   000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000081fcc082              00  0000000000  9                      05123     0085800050.                             00000000
'@

$sample.Substring(249, 5) # 05032

You would need to also use -Raw on your Get-Content call to get the file content as a single multi-line string instead of an string array. So, in summary, the condition you're likely looking for should be:
if ((Get-Content 'C:\appoggio\*.TXT' -Raw).Substring(249, 5) -eq '05032') {
    Set-Location C:\appoggio\prova -WhatIf
    Write-Warning 'ok'
}

You should also consider that this can get the content of multiple files since you're using a wildcard (*.txt) so this condition might fail in that case and there is likely a better way of doing this if you add more information to your question.
